How can I validate in NestJs a dynamic DTO as a property?
export class MongoIDDto {
  @ApiProperty({
    description: 'Id',
    required: true,
    type: String,
    default: '61d9cfbf17ed7311c4b3e485',
  })
  @IsMongoId()
  @IsString()
  id: string;
}

export class PaginateQueryDto<T> {
  @IsOptional()
  limit: number;

  @IsOptional()
  page: number;

  @Allow()
  offset: number;

  @IsOptional()
  sort: string | Record<string, 'asc' | 'desc' | 1 | -1>;

  @IsOptional()
  select: string | Record<string, 0 | 1>;

  @IsOptional()
  @IsObject()
  filters: Record<string, string>;

  @IsOptional()
  @ValidateNested()
  @Type(() => Object)
  params: T;
}

I have this DTO which has a property that is based on another DTO. If I implement it as follows:
async findAll(@Query() query: PaginateQueryDto<MongoIDDto>) {
  console.log(query, '----------------query');
  ...
}

The result is:
{
  limit: 5,
  page: 2,
  offset: 5,
  sort: { color: 'asc', name: 1, age: -1 },
  select: { name: 1 },
  filters: { name: 'SomeName' },
  params: { id: 'someExtraProperty' }
} ----------------query'

I expect the nested DTO validation is applied and responds with an error if the id property does not contain a value of type mongoId.
This should return an error:
{
  limit: 5,
  page: 2,
  offset: 5,
  sort: { color: 'asc', name: 1, age: -1 },
  select: { name: 1 },
  filters: { name: 'SomeName' },
  params: { id: 'someExtraProperty' }
} ----------------query'

This should pass the validation:
{
  limit: 5,
  page: 2,
  offset: 5,
  sort: { color: 'asc', name: 1, age: -1 },
  select: { name: 1 },
  filters: { name: 'SomeName' },
  params: { id: '65fb3a13a4721100124332eb' }
} ----------------query'

How can I validate the nested DTO in NestJS with class-validator?
